# Where is C code of Simulink stateflow model?

Tags: matlab

I designed a state-machine with evens and transitions in Simulink (Matlab). All i did was gave some timer events and made it jump from one state to other. It works perfectly fine. Now the question is where can I see the C code that corresponds to state machine? Where are these files stored?

Answer (score 2):

To view the automatically generated C-code, you require the Simulink Coder product. Find more information on this topic at the Stateflow product page here:

http://www.mathworks.com/products/stateflow/description5.html

hope that helps,
Siddharth